# Elasticsearch Client returns timestamp as string

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, nestjs

I want to fetch some logs data from elasticsearch and return it to the UI using graphql.
I am using the [nestjs/elasticsearch](https://github.com/nestjs/elasticsearch) client in my nest.js backend which is a wrapper of '[elastic/elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch)'.
I have also mapped the timestamp field in the elasticsearch index as 'date'.

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
        },
        "message": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
    }
}
```

I have created the @ObjectType class as follows:

```
@ObjectType()
export class LogMessage {

  @Field()
  message: string;

  @Field()
  timestamp: Date;
   
}
```

But, while getting the documents from Elasticsearch, the timestamp is getting returned as a 'string'.
And because the `ObjectType` expects 'timestamp' to be a Date, I get 'null' on the 'graphql' response for the 'timestamp' field.
Changing to 'timestamp: string', I see the timestamp in the response.

How do I debug this issue and make sure that elasticsearch client returns the 'timestamp' as a 'Date'?
Or
Is this expected behavior and I need to convert the string to Date type manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expected behavior as ElasticSearch render date as a String. So as you mentioned, you need to convert string to date type.
Please check this [Date Field documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) of elasticsearch.

Below is snippet from doc:

> JSON doesn’t have a date data type, so dates in Elasticsearch can
> either be:
>
> - strings containing formatted dates, e.g. "2015-01-01" or "2015/01/01    12:10:30".
> - a number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch.
> - a number representing seconds-since-the-epoch (configuration).

Also from the same doc:

> Dates will always be rendered as strings, even if they were initially
> supplied as a long in the JSON document.

Comment: @dhruvparekh12 Please mark as answer if it is help you.

Comment: Got it. Thank you @sagar-patel